# How do I access assets/public folder from routed page in Meteor?

Tags: html, meteor, iron-router

I am building a multipage app with Meteor and I am trying to access public assets from a routed page.

For example, when I navigate to this route `http://localhost:3000/editor`, I want to be able to use an image from this source: `public/img/thing.png` like so:

```
<img src='img/thing.png'>
```

But it doesn't work since I am at a different URL.

*Is there any handlebar helper which I need to insert in there to get my root URL?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No handlebars, just regular HTML:

```
<img src='/img/thing.png'>
```